# Как передать список в другой активити?

Tags: java, android, list, activity, список

Как передать список `List<data_Users> listTemp;` из класса `Read` в другое активити?
через `putextra` что-то не получается.

класс Read:

```
  package com.example.ddf;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class Read extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listView;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
        List<String> listdata;
        List<data_Users> listTemp;
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        private DatabaseReference myData;
        private String USER_KEY="big";
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.read_layout);
            init();
            GetDatafromdb();
            SetOnClickItem();
        }
    
        private void init(){
            listView=findViewById(R.id.listview1);
            listdata=new ArrayList<>();
            listTemp=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listdata);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            myData= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
        }
    
        private void GetDatafromdb(){
            ValueEventListener vevlistener1 = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(listdata.size()>0)
                        listdata.clear();
                    if(listTemp.size()>0)
                        listTemp.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        data_Users users=ds.getValue(data_Users.class);   //чтение данных одного ребенка
                        assert users!=null;
                        listdata.add(users.name);
                        listTemp.add(users);
    
                    }
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                }
            };
            myData.addValueEventListener(vevlistener1);
            //Users user = listTemp.get(1);
    
        }
    
        private void SetOnClickItem(){
            Intent intent_list;
            intent_list = new Intent(Read.this, ListActivity.class);
           // Bundle args = new Bundle();
           // for(data_Users obj:listTemp)    //можно передать список string, а у меня структура
            //    temp = obj;
            ListActivity listActivity = new ListActivity();
            //args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)listTemp);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //data_Users user = listTemp.get(position);
                    //listActivity.setList(listTemp);
                    //Toast.makeText(Read.this, "listtemp size="+listActivity.listTemp.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    //        .show();
                    intent_list.putExtra("firebase", (Serializable) listTemp);
                    startActivity(intent_list);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

класс где принимаю список:

```
 public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Intent intent;
        List<data_Users> listTemp;
        final int limit_index_csv = 300;   //для таблицы. до какого элемента считать. 2385
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);
            //прием из read
            listTemp = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("firebase");
```

Comment: У вас должен быть класс data_Users - Serializable. И, соответственно, надо получать getSerializableExtra. Ну и вас очень много нарушений правил именования классов/переменных - код в итоге плохо читаем.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как такой класс объявить?

Comment: да, что-то получилось. теперь надо понять как из объекта Serializable получать данные

Comment: короче я нашел.
класс data_Users сделал implements Serializable.
класс Read не трогал.

а для того чтобы прочитать надо написать так:
listTemp=new ArrayList((Collection<? extends data_Users>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("firebase"));

Comment: Можно Parcelable использовать и получать из intent как getParcelableArrayListExtra, а данные закидывать через соответствующий класс, см. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable